# Seek time and latency on disc for a file that is stored sequentially?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-hardware, memory-access

Say there is a file that is sequentially organized over 2.5 tracks on a disc. I'm assuming there would be a non-zero value for seek time and latency when accessing the first track, but what about the remaining 1.5 tracks?

I know it wouldn't actually be zero but I'm talking about a negligible value. When the head moves from the first track to the next, do you assume the next wanted data follows immediately after the end of the last track or would you assume that head just misses the correct sector and the disc has to spin once first?

Sorry for the verbosity, first year CompSci student and this is all very new to me.